# Template non-type parameter overload

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to have two template classes with the same name but different non-type template parameters - thus some kind of non-type template parameter overload mechanism?

```
template <typename T, typename U, void (T::*F)(U)> void common() { ... }
template <typename T, typename U, void (T::*F)(const U &)> void common() { ... }

struct Foo
{
   void foo(bool) {}
}

struct Bar
{
   void bar(const bool &) {}
}

template <typename T, typename U, void (T::*F)(U)> struct Storage 
{
     Storage() { common <T, U, F>(); }
}
template <typename T, typename U, void (T::*F)(const U &)> struct Storage 
{
    Storage() { common <T, U, F>(); }
}

Storage<Foo, bool, &Foo::foo> foo;
Storage<Bar, bool, &Bar::bar> bar;
```

The reason for having such a mechanism is that both should be able to be created using the same macro.

```
#define STORAGE(T, U, F) Storage<T, U, F> BOOST_PP_CAT(storage, __LINE__);

STORAGE(Foo, bool, &Foo::foo)
STORAGE(Bar, bool, &Bar::bar)
```

Thanks for your input!

**EDIT**

May be some further input is helpful.

What I want to achieve is a method to be run at initialization time. I can provide such a method - or better said two overloaded methods, one with the const-ref and one with the value-member-function-pointer; but to execute them at initilization time I usually would have a stub class (like Storage in this case) which calls this method in its constructor (and so at initialization time, as the STORAGE macro creates an instance of the stub class).

To use the same STORAGE macro I have to have the same template non-type 'overloads' for the stub class I have for the functions to be executed (and I will have to template the class and not the constructor, which I certainly could overload, because it isn't possible to explicitly state constructor template parameters and as the template parameters are non-type I can't have them deduced as well).

**EDIT**

The pointer to member function has to be a compile-time value (a non-type template parameter) as it will be wrapped in a non-template static method, which then can be stored in a std::vector available at runtime.

Comment: Ask the same with functions instead of classes for more fun ;-) Your goal is achievable with some partial specializations, but not that directly.

Comment: But where is the fun then? ;-) How would you solve that using partial specializations (as you can't specialize a non-type template parameter).

Comment: You can specialize on decltype(F). So you would use `Storage<T,U,decltype(F)>::Inside<F>` (there are a few tricks if you need a C++03 version).

Comment: If you only need the function in the constructor, you don't need to make it a template parameter of the class, you could simply pass it as argument to the constructor.

Comment: Marc Glisse: We have to support C++03, so no decltype :-( But I'm quite interested in hearing your 'few tricks'.

Comment: Marc Glisse: No I can't, because I need a compile time value (a non-type template parameter) not a runtime value (an argument).

Comment: You can overload a function `select` to take either a `void (T::*F)(U)` or a `void (T::*F)(U const&)` and return types of different size in the 2 overloads. Then you can use `sizeof(select(F))` instead of `decltype(F)` to separate the 2 cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what problem you're trying to solve. If you're just trying to get your example to work, you can change the 'bool' to 'const bool&'. Does this achieve what you wanted?

```
template <typename T, typename U, void (T::*F)(U)> void common() {  }

struct Foo
{
    void foo(bool) {}
};

struct Bar
{
    void bar(const bool &) {}
};

template <typename T, typename U, void (T::*F)(U)>
struct Storage 
{
        Storage() { common <T, U, F>(); }
};

Storage<Foo, bool, &Foo::foo> foo;
Storage<Bar, const bool&, &Bar::bar> bar;
```